# Can I place Remoting configuration in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, remoting

I have an ASP.Net web application, which interacts with .Net Remoting application server. As part of this is it possible to place Remoting Client Configuration in Web.config file? If so, how it can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can place it in the Web.config.

Have a look at [Configure .NET Remoting When the Remoting Client Is an ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323490)

and [ASP.NET Configuration Web.Config Files Elements](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=430)